# Is F# 3.0 runtime redistributable?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

Is legally OK to redistribute F# 3.0 runtime (FSharp.Core.dll versions 2.3.0.0, 4.3.0.0), and where do I find proof of that? I prepared a NuGet package with those but having second thoughts about licensing before publishing the package. Microsoft released F# 2.0 runtime as a redist package - so no questions there, but my impression is that the only way to get F# 3.0 runtime is through installing VS 2011 or similar; I am not sure where is the license to check that redistributing the F# runtime is OK.

Note that the question is only about the binaries signed with Microsoft key. Sources for the code are available under Apache license.

Having the NuGet package with the DLLs would make some build situations easier.

The open-source F# repository went ahead and is redistributing Microsoft-signed FSharp.Core.dll (see https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp), but I still would like to make sure this is allowed.

Comment: Did you send an e-mail to the F# team?

Comment: I did yes, waiting. Will post if they reply.

Comment: Seems the answer is positive. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fsharp-opensource/VQawzPvLKPI/HIBz1iw9Z1UJ

Comment: @alxx and the rest of people voting to close this - search for "license" on SO and you find 1000s of questions with about 10% of them closed as off-topic. Do you really think you are doing a service to humanity marking them as closed? I mean - no harm done, but are you using your time to do something good? Think about it. SO FAQ may need to be revised - questions about licensing show up here so often because they are part of developer's life, as is SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, F# 3.0 runtime can be redistributed. The EULA can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34675

Thanks to Don Syme's for his answer at the F# Open Source forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fsharp-opensource/VQawzPvLKPI/HIBz1iw9Z1UJ

Comment: Can i re-distribute *just* the FSharp.Core.dll, and in that case does it require me to bundle the FSharp Runtime EULA? or do I have to re-distribute the entire installer?