# Redistributable version of FSharp.Core.dll?

Tags: f#, mono, unity-game-engine

I have developed a commercial extension for the Unity3D game engine in F#, it's a piece of code which extends the editor with advanced node/graph editing features. F# is perfect for this due to the nature of immutability and DU's.

But, to my question: I realized that the license for the FSharp.Core.dll which comes with Microsoft .NET/Visual Studio probably doesn't allow you to re-distribute it with a commercial project? How would I go about finding out if this is the case or not, and if it's not is there any way to create my own compiled version of FSharp.Core.dll which would run on Unity3D?

The reason I ask is because Unity3D uses Mono 2.6 (albeit a modified version, to my understanding) under the hood, and there is no FSharp.Core.dll bundled with the editor, so I need to supply my own with my extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is F# 3.0 runtime redistributable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207738/is-f-3-0-runtime-redistributable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [Is F# 3.0 runtime redistributable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207738/is-f-3-0-runtime-redistributable)

The answer is of course Yes. The language would be pretty useless if its core library wasn't re-distributable...

Comment: Can i re-distribute just the FSharp.Core.dll, and in that case does it require me to bundle the FSharp Runtime EULA? or do I have to re-distribute the entire installer?

Comment: @thr Well fsc has the --standalone flag which lets you actually bake the FSharp.Core.dll into your own assembly. So given it can do that, it seems safe you don't need to worry about installer!

Comment: @nbevans: Oh I had no idea about --standalone, that kind of fits perfectly for my problem

Comment: @thr Also check out --staticlink. Both are pretty cool. Basically fsc has ILMerge built right into if you want to use it.